# Sparql- how to get number of triples?

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'm doing a small exercise on sparql. Using [Dbpedia Endpoint](https://dbpedia.org/sparql), I need to count number of triples.

This is my query

```
      // Get the number of triples //


    SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?Triples) WHERE { ?s ?p ?o}
-------------------------------------------------------
    OUTPUT:

    ( ?Triples = 1625382483 )
```

Just wondering are  the query and the result right?
Is this how you get the number of triples?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can sanity check many things by executing queries directly on a SPARQL endpoint, rather than going through Jena or other intermediary clients.  For instance, [your query on the DBpedia form](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=SELECT%20%28COUNT%28*%29%20as%20%3FTriples%29%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), and [its results](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%20%28COUNT%28*%29%20as%20%3FTriples%29%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), which shows all triples in that triplestore ([currently 1,625,382,483](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%20%28COUNT%28*%29%20as%20%3FTriples%29%20WHERE%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query)).

If you want the count of triples only within the DBpedia named graph ([currently 438,336,517](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%20%28COUNT%28*%29%20as%20%3FTriples%29%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20GRAPH%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)), you'll need to specify that, either [in the SPARQL form *Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI)*](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20%28COUNT%28*%29%20as%20%3FTriples%29%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D%20%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), or [directly in the query](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=SELECT%20(COUNT(*)%20as%20%3FTriples)%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20GRAPH%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20), as in --

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?Triples) 
WHERE 
  { GRAPH <http://dbpedia.org> 
      { ?s ?p ?o } 
  }
```

-- or --

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) as ?Triples) 
FROM <http://dbpedia.org> 
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
```